# JavaScript Encryption Method

Tags: javascript, html, encryption

I have a friend who specializes in IT and networking technology. He sent me a JavaScript function to correct some of the syntax errors so he could use it. He told me it was an encryption method.

After it was all corrected and I sent it back to him, I embedded it into an HTML file to see exactly what it does. I found out that no matter what sort of HTML tags you include in the file, it turns up as a blank web page. I looked through developer tools on my browser and I can see that the HTML tags are there, but they don't show up.

I am curious; how does the script do this? And what purpose could it serve?

**Code:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script
        function crypo() {
            var temp = "", i, c = 0, out = "";
            var str = "72&101&108&108&111&32&73&32&97&109&32&84&48&49&51&32&10&73&102&32&121&111
            &117&32&99&97&110&32&100&101&99&111&100&101&32&116&104&105&115&32&109&101&115&115&
            97&103&101&32&73&32&119&111&117&108&100&32&108&105&107&101&32&116&111&111&32&116&9
            7&108&107&10&72&111&112&101&102&117&108&108&121&32&121&111&117&32&99&97&110&32&102
            &105&110&100&32&109&101&";
            while(c <= str.length - 1){
                while(str.charAt(c) != '&') {
                    temp = temp + str.charAt(c++);
                    c++;
                    out = out + String.fromCharCode(temp);
                    temp = "";
                }
            }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>You Can't See Me</h1>
    <p>I don't appear on the web page</p>
</body>
```

**Note:** the header and paragraph are there just to show that they don't turn up in the web page.

Comment: Whatever that is, it's not really correct to call it an "encryption" method. It looks like a string of simple UTF-8 character codes that the function is attempting (incorrectly) to turn into a string of the corresponding characters. And it certainly won't hide all the contents of the page; it doesn't do anything with the string it builds.

Comment: str = 'garbage';
out = str.split('&').map(function(c){return String.fromCharCode(c)}).join('');  

is a one liner that does the same thing... correctly, in case that was a thing he wanted. This isn't encryption, or even a cipher, it just takes a list of numbers associated with letters, and turns them into the associated letters. It'd keep out novices but that's about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The script start tag is missing its `>`.
2. The content of the script is treated as a bunch of invalid attributes
3. The `>` for the script end tag is treated as the `>` for the script *start* tag
4. The rest of the document is treated as (invalid) JavaScript (and possibly not parsed at all because the document ends before you have a script end tag) because it is inside the script element.

The content of the script element is actually irrelevant.

**Use a [validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/)!**

Comment: Oh my goodness...I can't believe I missed that! I thought I knew HTML, but I guess I should remember the basics! Thank you!

Comment: Validator, if you're stuck like this, but even before that I'd recommend an editor with code color syntax highlighting.